# One-digit products in a row of numbers, base-N

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Generalizing [One-digit products in a row of numbers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89413/one-digit-products-in-a-row-of-numbers) to base-N:

For which bases N does there exist at least one solution to the following:
"The digits from 1 to N can be arranged in a row, such that any two neighbouring digits in this row is the product of two one-digit numbers"?

Examples:

> base-10: 728163549
>  ...
>  base-16: D24E1879A5B6C3F

Comment: Do you know the answer to this?

Comment: @DonThousand: obviously people can come up with heuristic solutions; I don't see an obvious constructive approach, although there might be one. There seems a pretty obvious generalization of [ArnaudMortier's heuristic](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89414/2349) to "products starting with digit (N-1)"

Comment: Did I accidentally use the word 'obvious' three times... doh

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not really about products, more about finding an arrangement of digits 1 to N-1 (for base N, since digit N does not exist in base N), that conforms to the criterion that any pair in the arrangement is part of the set of single digit products.

There could be a better way to solve this, but I wrote a small program that creates a table of possible digit combinations and uses that to try to find a valid arrangement.

It's not optimal in terms of performance (essentially a depth-first-search), but finding a pattern for base-N takes N times longer than for base-N-1.

> this My program was able to show that bases 3, 4, 5, and 6 do not have such an arrangement (due to digits that do not exist in a product).
>
> Interestingly, for base-2 (binary) it thinks that "1" is a valid combination due to the only non-zero digit being 1, so the row has no neighbouring digits.
>
> Otherwise it shows that bases 7 to 21 have possible arrangements of digits.
>
> ```
> base-2:  1 (questionable)
> base-3:  -
> base-4:  -
> base-5:  -
> base-6:  -
> base-7:  513426
> base-8:  5243617
> base-9:  46271538
> base-10: 728163549
> base-11: 739158264a
> base-12: 384765a192b
> base-13: 35786a294b1c
> base-14: 385b27a496c1d
> base-15: 375d1b4a698c2e
> base-16: 375b6e19c4d2a8f
> base-17: 35b8e2ac6f17d49g
> base-18: 397af2d6bc5e48g1h
> base-19: 37bca59g2d8h1f4e6i
> base-20: 35h28be97cf6dag4i1j
> ```
>
> Here's a [link](https://tio.run/##ZVJZT4NAEH7fXzGSNIBALK1nIw@etd5HPRsedu1WqXSogEo1/vY6C7Q08Y395pv5jjCepK8RNqfT/U67070BD7S622iurq1vbG5x8dyXg5fXYPgWjjAav8dJ@vH5lU2@d3b39g8O20ed45PTs/OLy6vrm@7t3f3D45PlgMZYGu3yRHohH4k@B7RFy9D1YAC4LUCGiYSCYODKirCFaVqFfC/A1MCaMH3GUGYp2fn5ZYxMwHM0ElFioA2hDZmn62aLAQyiGDgECEkUp7JvYI4CkBTJRqkaZcCxT88lD/S6XsxzRgieB@4MAJgEMiRi@VY2q5kSEurazAe563Gf3Dgu@bG4WXHnl8ACwdh8Neb4Io2GDW59bh7VoAzvtoRfXMmvo0/xdb0kBtUFUWopePgfpnVaLAsOYBmGNghzIbZE6kllb@TNYM/1Z10Vwr2671dxKgwsL2czmsksSNKEhA45FVWaVOUslLSQiyw4bmlwvtqNP2SOiFjyNwD6HsfqF9AEeXdqSUurCbu8Opjt5f@P5mjmdPoH</p) to a program you can run in your browser.

Comment: *"The problem is not really about products, more about finding an arrangement of digits 1 to N-1"* I know that, I already hinted so above. I merely reused the phrasing of @ThomasL's original question for obvious reasons.

Comment: The base-2 solution is trivially true, since there's only one non-zero digit.

Comment: Sorry, never posted here before, took a while to figure out how to put code in spoiler tags.